# Cutting out irrregular parts of a mesh out

Tags: modeling

I work with reconstructing fossil skeletons of human ancestors. Bones are usually incomplete and I need to assemble whole virtual bones from laser scans of different fossil parts of the bone I have scanned. How can I efficiently delete parts I don't need so that I can assemble whole virtual bones? I know it's easy to delete by bisecting, but that's not enough for what I need  [image]Does this image help explain what I wantto do?

Comment: could you please show a screenshot or something similar

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I have added a screenshot annotated in Powerpoint

Comment: Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94065/cut-mesh-in-half-with-filled-faces

Comment: Please avoid text that is relevant to the question as part of the image. It cannot be edited for clarity and, more importantly, search engines cannot read it. The post is less useful this way, other users with similar issues will have a harder time finding the information they need.

Comment: How is bisect not enough?  That's the simplest thing that would do the operation you're requesting in the image-- it's hard to know what you're looking for without understanding why that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

You can try centering the mesh in an axis (X or Y most commonly) and then use <kbd>numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>numpad 3</kbd> to get an isometric view of the mesh along that axis. (Depending on your blender config, you might need to also press <kbd>numpad 5</kbd>)

Then you can press <kbd>z</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd> to go into wireframe mode and edit mode respectively.

Once there, you can select whatever vertices are not needed (To select vertices you can use the hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and select vertices in the popup menu) and delete them. Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> again to go back to object mode and add a mirror modifier to mirror the whole "correct" side of the mesh along the axis you need. Fiddle around with the merge and clipping options to get whatever desired effect you were looking for.

Comment: @Robin Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to select non manifold vertices, essentially finding all holes and floating vertices in a mesh.