# Cut mesh in half with filled faces?

Tags: modeling

I would like to cut this mesh into two parts where the Plane is located and have the resulting openings filled. I've tried the knife tool and bisect but I can't figure out how to execute either of them. I did see a similar question here maybe a year ago but I can't find it. Thanks in advance!

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the result I am after (I did this by hand).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers will work, but two other options need to be given.
1. Booltool addon - add a Solidify modifier to the Plane object, and then shift-select your target object and choose Difference bool brush. 
2. With all the faces selected, you can use Shift-K to draw the knife tool through the mesh in edit mode so that it creates a cut even through odd ngons. After, you can select this new loop and use V to rip and then select one side and separate like explained before.

Comment: Booltool isn't? I woudl think that it was, since the result is a closed mesh on each side. The knife tool means manual work, and that is going along with the other solutions presented.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you can create a loopcut on the mesh where the plane currently is, then select the loop and press V, and then drag the loop to the side. This will split the mesh and create an opening that you can fill.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can press Crtl-R in Edit mode and select the loop direction you want and then the location of the knife cut. This will create a straight line made of edges around the the mesh. You can then select one half and press P, then separate by selected.